# How do you direct an ASP.NET MVC route to a static file?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an Angular2 app (RC1) that is bootstrapped from index.html.  I want to setup an ASP.NET Core (RC2) route that sends all route requests with the pattern localhost/fs/* to the index.html file in wwwroot.  Any thoughts?

I know I can do this with a MVC HomeController and Index view.  But, I was hoping to not need a view controller.  I am using MVC for API controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution to serve static file - use `UseStaticFiles` in `Startup.cs`.

As soon as you need to "redirect" several incoming urls into one static file - I think best decision is to [write custom middleware](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/middleware.html) which will check incoming requests and rewrite `Path` when required. Then place this middleware before `UseStaticFiles` in `Startup.Configure`. This will work without MVC.

Of course this custom middleware may redirect user to `/index.html` file (send 301 / 302 http status code with `Location` http-header), and user will make another request for index file, but I don't think you need this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... This seems to only option I can think of at the time!